# How to solve "Navigation action/destination android:id/home cannot be found" error on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-architecture-navigation

I am implementing the Navigation Component in Android and I have a problem only in one point.

Everything works fine, but when I press the back button **on the top bar**, this error appears on the console (as a fact to keep in mind, the message does not appear **if I press the device's physical back button**):

> I/NavigationUI: Ignoring onNavDestinationSelected for MenuItem
> android:id/home as it cannot be found from the current destination
> Destination(org.my.app:id/nav_tercia) label=Tercia
> class=org.my.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination android:id/home cannot be found from the current destination
> Destination(org.my.app:id/nav_tercia) label=Tercia
> class=org.my.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1650)
> at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1582)
> at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(NavigationUI.kt:96)
> at org.deiverbum.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment$1.onMenuItemSelected(BreviarioDataFragment.java:108)
> at androidx.core.view.MenuHostHelper.onMenuItemSelected(MenuHostHelper.java:107)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ComponentActivity.java:553)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:264)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:269)
> at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
> at androidx.appcompat.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:188)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)

The App returns to the previous fragment, but I want to remove that message, a sign that something is wrong.

This is the Fragment method where the problem occurs:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requireActivity().addMenuProvider(new MenuProvider() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater menuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
            voiceItem=menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz);
            voiceItem.setVisible(isVoiceOn);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) {
                //Some code here
                requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return true;
            }
            NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(requireParentFragment());
            return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
        }
    }, getViewLifecycleOwner(), Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);

    binding = FragmentBreviarioDataBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    // ...
    return root;
}
```

Debugging, the problem is these two lines:

```
            NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(requireParentFragment());
            return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
```

If I change them to a `return false;` the message described above does not appear, but **some options that I have in the top bar and that I have integrated into the Navigation Component do not work for me**.

In the `navigation` XML the Fragment has this destination assigned to it:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_tercia"
    android:name="org.deiverbum.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_fragment_tercia"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_breviario_data" >
    <argument
        android:name="hourId"
        app:argType="integer"
        android:defaultValue="3" />
</fragment>
```

I tried to also add this inside `fragment` to see if it would recognize the navigation to `home`, but nothing:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/home"
        app:destination="@id/home" />
```

Is there a way to remove that annoying message?

Comment: I have the same problem. it seems that some menuItem with id home is hardcoded somewhere when you press the back button on the toolbar. Have you find any solution yet?

Comment: @IvanLopes my solution was migrate the code to Menu Provider, see [this post](https://proandroiddev.com/menuprovider-api-android-208465c80a54) for more details.